# proper way to sign .net core assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, strongname

I'm trying to sign a .net core lib, and I'm just not sure if I did everything correctly

1) using VS Command Promp I called `sn -k mykey.snk`

2) copied `mykey.snk` to myproject folder

3) in `project.json` added keyfile

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {}
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "outputName": "MyLib",
    "keyFile": "mykey.snk"
  }
```

is this correct, is the library (dll) going to be usable on both .net core and full .net 4.6 apps ?

Comment: That looks correct. Are you experiencing any issues with your signed assembly?

Comment: no issues yet, I haven't found an official doc on how to do this, and there's no signing tab in VS with .net core, so I had to guess/google a bit

Comment: just want to mention that, now dotnet core dosen't recommend strong names your assemblies. [link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/strong-name-signing.md)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way. If you look into any [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet) projects, like [Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/project.json), you will find

```
"buildOptions": {
   "keyFile": "../../tools/Key.snk"
   ...
}
```

in project.json file, and Key.snk in [Tools](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/tools) folder. You also may check [.NET Core - strong name assemblies](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/124) issue.

Comment: how the validation works when .net core app is running on Linux box?